# record jQUery element inside a array

Tags: jquery, html

I declared a array variable `els = [];` in which I want to store jquery elments which are created at some point within certain events:

```
els[file.id] = $('<li></li>');
$('body').append(els[file.id]);
```

file.id is a unique id generated by the plupload script which I'm using (the event is from it)

But it doesnt work, the array is always empty...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arrays can only have sequential, numeric keys. You can't choose arbitrary keys. To use arbitrary key-value pairs, use an object:

```
var els = {};
```

With that said, the code you've written *should* still work (even though `els.length` would be 0) – perhaps this isn't a complete code sample?

Comment: ok now I see the contents of the variable with console.log but I dont know why the dom is not being updated with the new elements which are added with append...